# Power management in Qualcomm SoCs vs CPUFreq based power management

Tags: linux, kernel, cpu, arm, cpu-frequency

https://www.qualcomm.com/news/onq/2013/10/25/power-vs-performance-management-cpu

I was going through the above document and read that "The Krait CPU cores of Snapdragon processors lie on separate voltage and frequency planes.  This allows each CPU core to hit independent frequencies and voltages, delivering scalable performance and power levels."

However, if I check the affected CPUs of DVFS policy, I see that for Snapdragon 845 (on a Pixel 3), there are two clusters of 4 cores each. This means that the power management of the 4 cores is tied together. Does that not contradict the above statement (as mentioned on Qualcomm's page)?

Comment: Is there any Operating System involvement here?

Comment: Yeah. That's what I think. So, Qualcomm supports independent voltage and frequencies for every core, but Linux CPUFreq ties them up. I just want to confirm this.